# I need assitance using query using extractValue

Tags: mysql, xml, extract-value

Can anyone help me display the client name and the client id for clients who own a bird that costs 250? I can seem to figure this one out.

Here is a non working solution:

```
 Select 
 extractValue(datax, '/client/cl_name' ) as Client
, extractValue(datax, 'client/@cl_id') as ClientID
from a_xml.xml_animals
Where extractValue(datax,'count(//animal/an_type[self:text()="bird" and an_price= 250])') > 0;
```

I have also tried:

```
Select 
, extractValue(datax, '/client/cl_name' ) as Client
, extractValue(datax, 'client/@cl_id') as ClientID
from a_xml.xml_animals
Where extractValue(datax,'count(//animal/an_type[self:text()="bird"])') > 0
and
extractValue (datax, 'count(/client[an_price= 250])')  > 0;
```

Here are the inserts and table I am working with:

```
use a_xml;

drop table if exists a_xml.xml_animals;

create table a_xml.xml_animals(
  id    int primary key
, datax TEXT)
;
truncate table a_xml.xml_animals;

insert into a_xml.xml_animals values (1,
'<client cl_id="8243"><cl_name>Johnson</cl_name><pets>
<animal><an_id>136</an_id><an_type>bird</an_type><an_name>ShowBoat</an_name><an_price>75</an_price></animal>
<animal><an_id>137</an_id><an_type>bird</an_type><an_name>Mr. Peanut</an_name><an_price>250</an_price></animal>
</pets></client>');

insert into a_xml.xml_animals values (2, 
'<client cl_id="3908"><cl_name>Nelson</cl_name><pets>
<animal><an_id>1201</an_id><an_type>cat</an_type>
<an_name>Ursula</an_name><an_name>Snookums</an_name><an_name>Mittens</an_name><an_price>500</an_price></animal>
</pets></client>');

 insert into a_xml.xml_animals values (3,
'<client cl_id="3775"><cl_name>Miller</cl_name><pets/></client>');

 insert into a_xml.xml_animals values (4,
'<client cl_id="8467"><cl_name>Miller</cl_name><pets>
<animal><an_id>205</an_id><an_type>bird</an_type><an_name>ShowBoat</an_name><an_price>75</an_price></animal>
<animal><an_id>207</an_id><an_type>bird</an_type><an_name>Mr. Peanut</an_name><an_price>150</an_price></animal>
<animal><an_id>212</an_id><an_type>bird</an_type><an_name>Tweet</an_name><an_price>275</an_price></animal>
<animal><an_id>215</an_id><an_type>bird</an_type><an_name>Charlie</an_name><an_price>380</an_price></animal>
</pets></client>');

 insert into a_xml.xml_animals values (5,
'<client cl_id="4578"><cl_name>Leeson</cl_name><pets>
<animal><an_id>358</an_id><an_type>bird</an_type><an_name>Archibald</an_name><an_price>275</an_price></animal>
<animal><an_id>369</an_id><an_type>cat</an_type><an_name>Smithers</an_name><an_name>Smuthers</an_name><an_price>250</an_price></animal>
<animal><an_id>3478</an_id><an_type>dog</an_type><an_name>Bossun</an_name><an_price>250</an_price></animal>
</pets></client>');

  insert into a_xml.xml_animals values (6,
'<client cl_id="9478"><cl_name>Terry</cl_name><pets>
<animal><an_id>658</an_id><an_type>bird</an_type><an_name>Archibald</an_name><an_price>275</an_price></animal>
<animal><an_id>669</an_id><an_type>bird</an_type><an_name>Smithers1</an_name><an_name>Smuthers2</an_name><an_price>250</an_price></animal><
animal><an_id>2478</an_id><an_type>bird</an_type><an_name>cat </an_name><an_price>250</an_price></animal>
</pets></client>');


  insert into a_xml.xml_animals values (7,
'<client cl_id="4478"><cl_name>Clyde</cl_name><pets>
<animal><an_id>101</an_id><an_type>bird</an_type><an_name>Archibald</an_name><an_price>275</an_price></animal>
<animal><an_id>102</an_id><an_type>cat</an_type><an_name>Smithers</an_name><an_name>Smuthers</an_name><an_price>250</an_price></animal>
<animal><an_id>103</an_id><an_type>dog</an_type><an_name>Bossun</an_name><an_price>250</an_price></animal>
<animal><an_id>301</an_id><an_type>bird</an_type><an_name>Archibald</an_name><an_price>275</an_price></animal>
<animal><an_id>201</an_id><an_type>cat</an_type><an_name>Smithers</an_name><an_name>Smuthers</an_name><an_price>250</an_price></animal>
<animal><an_id>401</an_id><an_type>dog</an_type><an_name>Bossun</an_name><an_price>250</an_price></animal>
</pets></client>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select 
, extractValue(datax, '/client/cl_name' ) as Client
, extractValue(datax, 'client/@cl_id') as ClientID
from a_xml.xml_animals
WHERE extractValue(datax, 'count(//animal[an_type="bird"])') > 0
AND extractValue(datax, 'count(//animal[an_price=250])') > 0;
```